# Jump function moves object horizontal after dash function

Tags: game-maker

I have a dash function in my game as well as a jump function. Both of them works completely fine all by themselves. The jump works find and the dash works fine, however, I want to be able to jump cancel from my dash. During my dash, when I try to hit the jump button, the charater object moves horizontally instead of vertically. It almost acts as a second dash.

What I want to happen is the character to be able to jump vertically out of my characters dash. Can someone guide me in the right direction to my desired results?

```
if (keyboard_check(ord("D")) && !place_meeting(x + 2, y, obj_hitbox_wall)) {
    x += 2;
    image_xscale =+1;
    directionFacing = "Right";
}
if (keyboard_check(ord("A")) && !place_meeting(x - 2, y, obj_hitbox_wall)) {
    x -= 2;
    image_xscale =-1;
    directionFacing = "Left";
}
///// WALL HIT DETECTION START /////
if (!place_meeting(x,y+2,obj_hitbox_wall)){
    gravity = .25;
    grounded = false;
} else {
    vspeed = 0;
    gravity = 0;
    grounded = true;
    jumpDash = false;
}
///// WALL HIT DETECTION STOP /////

///// DOUBLE JUMP PROPERTIES START /////
if (grounded == false && jumped == true) {
    if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space)) {
        vspeed = 0;
        vspeed -= 5;
        jumped = false;
    }
}


if (grounded == true) {
    if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space)) {
        vspeed -=5;
        jumped = true;
    }
}
///// DOUBLE JUMP PROPERTIES END /////

///// DASH PROPERTIES START /////
if (dashed == false && keyboard_check_pressed(vk_shift) && jumpDash == false) {
    if (directionFacing = "Right") {
        vspeed = 0;
        gravity = 0;
        speed += 8;
        dashed = true;
    } 

    if (directionFacing = "Left") {
        vspeed = 0;
        gravity = 0;
        if (grounded == true) {
            speed -= 8;
        } else {
            speed+=8;
        }
        dashed = true;
    }

}

if (dashed == true && directionFacing = "Right") {
     speed -= .4;
     direction = 0;
    if (speed <= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0;
    }
}

if (dashed == true && directionFacing = "Left") {
    if (grounded == true){
        speed += .4;
        direction = 0;
    } else {
        speed -= .4;
        direction = 180;
    }
    if (grounded == true && speed >= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    } else if (grounded == false && speed <= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    }
}
///// DASH PROPERTIES END /////

///// JUMP DASH PROPERTIES START /////
if (grounded == false && dashed == true) {
    jumpDash = true;
}
///// JUMP DASH PROPERTIES END /////
```

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend trying to clean up and reduce the number of variables you are keeping track of, as more bugs are likely to develop.

But on to your question:

The problem you are seeing is that jumping out of a dash appears to be acting like a second dash rather than a jump. This would tell me that there is a problem around how you are setting `speed` and `vspeed`.

The only place you are setting the character to move at "dashing speed" is in the dash block, which means this has to be evaluating to true:

```
if (dashed == false && keyboard_check_pressed(vk_shift) && jumpDash == false) {
```

So we can break this down to try to understand how that may resolve to true when you don't expect it to.

First, let's look at how `dashed == false` could evaluate to true.

The only places you are setting dashed to false are in this block (I've removed some of the code to expose the logic a little more clearly):

```
if (dashed == true && directionFacing = "Right") {
    if (speed <= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0;
    }
}

if (dashed == true && directionFacing = "Left") {
    if (grounded == true && speed >= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    } else if (grounded == false && speed <= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    }
}
```

Let's summarize the conditions. We set dashed to false if:

1. Player is dashing right, and speed <= 0
2. Player is dashing left and they are grounded with speed >= 0
3. Player is dashing left and they are not grounded with speed <= 0

Next piece of logic is:

```
keyboard_check_pressed(vk_shift)
```

If you press shift, this is true.

Last piece is:

```
jumpDash == false
```

The only place you set this to false is in your collision logic:

```
if (!place_meeting(x,y+2,obj_hitbox_wall)){
    gravity = .25;
    grounded = false;
} else {
    vspeed = 0;
    gravity = 0;
    grounded = true;
    jumpDash = false;
}
```

So if the player is grounded, jump dash stays false.

The only variable to this bug seems to be how the `speed` variable is being set.

Putting it all together, it appears to me that this bug may only affect the player when moving `left`. My evidence to support this claim:

Player dashes left while grounded (hits this block of code):

```
    if (directionFacing = "Left") {
        vspeed = 0;
        gravity = 0;
        if (grounded == true) {
            speed -= 8;
        } else {
            speed+=8;
        }
        dashed = true;
    }
```

At this point `speed -= 8` is hit and the player how has `speed <= 0`

While dashing, the player tries to jump by hitting space, triggering this block of code:

```
if (grounded == true) {
    if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_space)) {
        vspeed -=5;
        jumped = true;
    }
}
```

You don't include the code where the player is actually being moved based on these variables, but since `vspeed -= 5` was hit, I assume the player will be moved off of the ground.

After one loop, the collision check sees that the player is no longer grounded:

```
if (!place_meeting(x,y+2,obj_hitbox_wall)){
    gravity = .25;
    grounded = false;
} else {
    vspeed = 0;
    gravity = 0;
    grounded = true;
    jumpDash = false;
}
```

At this point we are in this state (roughly):

- `directionFacing = "Left"`
- `dashed = true`
- `speed <= 0`
- `grounded = false`

This sets us up to fall into this block of code:

```
if (dashed == true && directionFacing = "Left") {
    if (grounded == true){
        speed += .4;
        direction = 0;
    } else {
        speed -= .4;
        direction = 180;
    }
    if (grounded == true && speed >= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    } else if (grounded == false && speed <= 0) {
        dashed = false;
        gravity = .25;
        speed = 0
    }
}
```

Specifically this piece will be triggered:

```
} else if (grounded == false && speed <= 0) {
   dashed = false;
   gravity = .25;
   speed = 0
}
```

Which will set `dashed = false`

Once that happens, if you're still holding down `vk_shift`, the dash condition is now true again:

```
if (dashed == false && keyboard_check_pressed(vk_shift) && jumpDash == false)
```

Which will result in a dash instead of continuing to jump.

It looks like if you were to let go of shift, and then press space, you'd be able to jump out of a dash as expected.

Hopefully my reasoning through this made sense. There may be a couple gaps here since I don't know exactly how the variable are being used when your game is stepping the world.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for this very well thought out explanation. Currently at work, so I will rework my code according to your answer when I am home. Will let you know how it goes.